# Compile java file in console

Tags: java

I have java file and a few libraries which I need to import. How to compile Test.java file in console and add in command libraries names?

```
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.Cluster;
import org.apache.cassandra.thrift.*;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocol;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Test extends Thread{
   //here my code
}
```

Comment: Aren't the libraries imported inside your Java program?

Comment: @Hunter: You still need to reference them when compiling in one way or another, how would it find the library files otherwise?

Comment: Not enough information - show Test.java at the minimum (but, this begs, why isn't the information you've researched from Oracle's Java references enough?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970182/how-to-compile-a-single-java-file

Comment: they are imported, but this does not solve the problem. I want include libraries names in console command, something like this: javac -cp "libraryname.jar" Test.java
How to write this command correctly,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this

Compile:

```
javac -cp /path/to/jar/files MyProgram.java
```

Run:

```
java -cp .;/path/to/jar/files  MyProgram
```

Here jar file correspond to external libraries.