# Haxe compile a single file for a large project

Tags: compilation, haxe

How can a single .hx file be compiled (to a .java file in my case) in a large project? Any @build macros would still be ran, so it could involve more than one .hx file, of course.

In Java this can be done (see: [How to compile a single Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970182/how-to-compile-a-single-java-file)). I am looking for a similar thing for Haxe.

Comment: Do you want to compile to a .jar file? It looks like you should be able to list the haxe classes in your build.hxml and the haxe compiler will put it into one jar. Is that what you're looking for? See the example build.hxml here: http://old.haxe.org/doc/start/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a java class from a hx file you can do so with a custom hxml file. Assuming the class doesn't have a complex set of dependencies you should be able to do this with the code below.

### Main.hx

```
class Main {
    public static function main() { 
        new package.to.ClassToImport(); 
    }
}
```

### build.hxml

```
-main Main
-java gen #this is the directory you will generate
```

Replace the `new package.to.ClassToImport()` statement with the correct path to the Haxe class you want to generate. If it requires additional imports the compilation may fail and you'll need to resolve those before compiling to java. Also, make sure you have `hxjava` installed via haxelib.